# same codes different outcomes in julia

Tags: julia

I have two codes:

1) First code:

```
Vp = EVw[:,:,1]
V0 = EV0

Va_test, Ca_test, Sa_test, Ta_test, EVa_test, Ap_test = [zeros(P.Na,P.Nh) for i in 1:6]
# interpolators
Vp_itp = interpolate((G.a, G.h), Vp, Gridded(Linear()))
V0_itp = interpolate((G.a,), V0, Gridded(Linear()))
# initialize state
a0 = G.a[1]
h0 = G.h[1]
# value function and budget constraints
VF(c,s,ak) = ValueFunctionTransfer(c,s,ak,a0,h0,r,w,Vp_itp,V0_itp,P,θ0)
BC(s) = BudgetConstraint(s,a0,h0,r,w,P)

# solve
for i in 1:P.Na, j in 1:P.Nh
# state
a0 = G.a[i]
h0 = G.h[j]
# solve
Ca_test[i,j], Sa_test[i,j], Ta_test[i,j], Va_test[i,j], Ap_test[i,j] = NestedGolden3D(VF,BC)
end
```

2) Second code:

```
Vp = EVw[:,:,1]
V0 = EV0

Va, Ca, Sa, Ta, EVa, Ap = [zeros(P.Na,P.Nh) for i in 1:6]
# interpolators
Vp_itp = interpolate((G.a, G.h), Vp, Gridded(Linear()))
V0_itp = interpolate((G.a,), V0, Gridded(Linear()))
# initialize state
a0 = G.a[1]
h0 = G.h[1]
# value function and budget constraints
VF(c,s,ak) = ValueFunctionTransfer(c,s,ak,a0,h0,r,w,Vp_itp,V0_itp,P,θ0)
BC(s) = BudgetConstraint(s,a0,h0,w,r,P)

# solve
for i in 1:P.Na, j in 1:P.Nh
# state
a0 = G.a[i]
h0 = G.h[j]
# solve
Ca[i,j], Sa[i,j], Ta[i,j], Va[i,j], Ap[i,j] = NestedGolden3D(VF, BC)
end
```

Both versions look the same to me, yet they deliver different outcomes!! What might be going on?

I had the second code in a function and I was not happy with the outcome. Then I created the first code in a different script and I got good results. I realized that both version were essentially the same, and then I made them look the same (other than the _test in the names).

They look exactly the same to me, but they do deliver different answer. I guess something is going on under the hood and I can't understand it.

To make sure that I'm running the codes correctly, I run the part that I need before (not shown), then I run one of the versions, save the results, and restart julia. Then I do the same with the other version. Then I restart julia again and I compare the results. They are not the same. I found this really puzzling.

Comment: You should wrap them both in a function. Then run them with the same input. It is hard to read code like this, without knowing the input.  Questions on stackoverflow should preferably contain code that can be run, including inputs. You can read about minimal working examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Actually, I don't think your question is suited to stackoverflow. You are basically looking for review of your code, in which case https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place to post it. I also notice that you are calling several functions which are not included in your post. If it is possible to make a proper MWE (minimal working example), then your question might be suitable. You can also consider posting to a Julia focused site, such as https://discourse.julialang.org/latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a difference between the two examples.

In the first example you had:

`BC(s) = BudgetConstraint(s,a0,h0,r,w,P)`

In the second example you had:

`BC(s) = BudgetConstraint(s,a0,h0,w,r,P)`